# wxPython application does not respond

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I have a complex application, with a GUI that needs to dialogue with some I/O devices and with some WebAPI. I put my wx.Frame class in the main file, as I read that the GUI should be in the main thread to avoid freezing

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Window()
    app.MainLoop()
```

but still the GUI freezes very often, and sometimes it doesn't show at all and a message saying "My_app is not responding" appears.
All the I/O and webAPI management is done in separate threads that are created by `frame`. The only GUI elements that are not in the main file are the pages that compose my notebook

```
from PageOne import PageOne
from PageTwo import PageTwo
from PageThree import PageThree

...

self.page1 = PageOne(self.nb)
self.page2 = PageTwo(self.nb)
self.page3 = PageThree(self.nb)

self.nb.AddPage(self.page1, "Page1")
self.nb.AddPage(self.page2, "Page2")
self.nb.AddPage(self.page3, "Page3")
```

All the communications between secondary threads and the GUI are done using `wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()` in the main file and `wx.PostEvent(self.parent, my_evt)` in the threads.

I am using wxpython 4.1.1 and Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Any suggestion on how to prevent the GUI from not responding or freezing? Is maybe a better idea to use multiprocessing instead of multithreading? I know that threads are usually better for I/O applications...but is it still true in my case where the threads are all enless loops?

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer per se.
However it might help track down a solution.
Given that we have no idea, `none`, what your code is doing, no one can answer a question like this.
It's the equivalent of asking, `How long is a piece of string?`

The best advice is to use something like the code below, adapting the `thread` to perform something akin to what your thread/threads are doing and see if you can replicate the behaviour and hopefully find the cause.

```
import time
import wx
from threading import Thread

import wx.lib.newevent
progress_event, EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class ThreadFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.btn = wx.Button(panel,label='Stop Long running process', size=(200,30), pos=(10,10))
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)
        self.progress = wx.Gauge(panel,size=(240,10), pos=(10,50), range=240)

        #Bind to the progress event issued by the thread
        self.Bind(EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT, self.OnProgress)
        #Bind to Exit on frame close
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)
        self.Show()

        self.mythread = TestThread(self)
        #Enable the GUI to be responsive by briefly returning control to the main App
        while self.mythread.isAlive():
            time.sleep(0.1)
            wx.GetApp().Yield()
            continue

        try:
            self.OnExit(None)
        except:
            pass

    def OnProgress(self, event):
        self.progress.SetValue(event.count)
        #or for indeterminate progress
        #self.progress.Pulse()

    def OnExit(self, event):
        if self.mythread.isAlive():
            self.mythread.terminate() # Shutdown the thread
            self.mythread.join() # Wait for it to finish
        self.Destroy()

class TestThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,parent_target):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent_target
        self.stopthread = False
        self.time = time.time()
        self.start()    # start the thread

    def run(self):
        # A loop that will run for 2 minutes then terminate
        while self.stopthread == False:
            curr_loop = int(time.time() - self.time)
            if curr_loop < 240:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                evt = progress_event(count=curr_loop)
                #Send back current count for the progress bar
                try:
                    wx.PostEvent(self.parent, evt)
                except: # The parent frame has probably been destroyed
                    self.terminate()
            else:
                self.terminate()

    def terminate(self):
        self.stopthread = True

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text_count = 0
        self.thread_count = 0
        self.parent=parent
        btn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label='Start Long running process', size=(200,30), pos=(10,10))
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Thread_Frame)
        btn2 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label='Is the GUI still active?', size=(200,30), pos=(10,50))
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.AddText)
        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style= wx.TE_MULTILINE, pos=(10,90),size=(400,100))

    def Thread_Frame(self, event):
        self.thread_count += 1
        frame = ThreadFrame(title='Threaded Task '+str(self.thread_count), parent=self.parent)

    def AddText(self,event):
        self.text_count += 1
        txt = "Gui is still active " + str(self.text_count)+"\n"
        self.txt.write(txt)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Main Frame', size=(600,400))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. As you said, yours is not exactly an answer, but it helped me understanding that a time.sleep(0.1) is needed. I know it was difficult to answer as I didn't give any detail on my code, but I am not authorized to do that. Anyway, my software needs to work more or less like a PLC; adding time.sleep(0.1) at the end of each endless-loop-thread allows the UI to be fast and responsive, without slowing down the software too much.

Comment: [continuation of previous comment] I didn't even think about sleep because every professor in my university taught me that sleep in PLC softwares is evil, they even reject your exam if they see a sleep in the code. That's true most of the time, maybe 99% of the times...but nobody ever showed me that 1% (like in my case) where it is not true, so it was difficult for me to figure that out

Comment: @Deffo Glad to have helped. Picture a hamster thrashing about on its exercise wheel, too busy to glance left or right. It will never know its food has arrived. It dies a noble death, never having allowed its wheel to stop. May be that's a bit esoteric!